# AngularJS: Problems with Binding in eventhandlers inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display buttons for choosing a username with ng-repeat. The display is OK. But every button in the loop has a ng-click directive with a binding. This is also displayed correct in Google Chromes DOM-Explorer. But when one of the buttons is clicked the eventhandling function login() has {{user.userId}} as input instead the value of the parameter.

Hers my code:

```
<div class="cell large-3" ng-repeat="user in userData()" ng-class="{'large-offset-1': ($index % 3) != 0}">
      <button ng-click="login('{{user.ID}}')" class="button expanded red bigButton"> {{user.userName}} </button>
    </div>
```

Cntrl:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('app').controller('loginCntrl', ['$scope', '$controller', '$location','dataService', 'mainService', initLoginCntrl]);
function initLoginCntrl($scope, $controller,$location, dataService, mainService) {
  angular.extend(this, $controller('baseCntrl', {
            $scope: $scope
        }));

  $scope.userData = dataService.getUserData;



  $scope.login = function(userID) { <-- input of userid is {{userData.ID}} instead of the eal userID from Binding
    mainService.login(userID);
  }
}
```

})();

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-click="login('{{userData.ID}}')"` -> `ng-click="login(userData.ID)"`

You are passing a string into that function.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help ! Your solution works. But I don't understand why i dont have to do the binding inside the n-repeat without the {{}}-brackets.

Comment: It relates to what is called "Interpolation" -> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation

Knowing when Angular will interpolate and not probably doesn't seem straight forward at first. It might take some time to get used to. The basic idea is that the `{{}}` will turn the variable into the value. You were passing a STRING value into the function though.... Put `ng-click="login('any string value here')"` in place and watch those words get passed into the function. It's because you were passing a string.

Comment: However, it would still be wrong to do: `ng-click="login({{userData.ID}})"` because you are passing a variable into the function. If you wanted to display the userData.ID on the page... then you would need the `{{}}`